# How to return String in anonymous class for a method returning void

Tags: java

I'm bit confused. I have the following:

```
public static String showInputDialog() {
   Form frm = new Form();
   final Command cmd = new Command("Ok");
   final TextField txt = new TextField("Enter the text", null, 1024, 0);
   frm.addCommand(cmd);
   frm.append(txt);
   frm.setCommandListener(new CommandListener() {

       public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
            if (c == cmd) {
                return txt.getString(); // Error !!
            } else {
                return null; // Error !!
            }
       }
   });
}
```

As you can see, I want to return the input dialog string, while the anonymous class method should return void. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: No ways to do this. Except when you are the author of `CommandListener`.

Comment: @madhead `CommandListener` is a built-in interface which has the method `CommandAction`. I cannot change the signature of an overriden method

Comment: You can't return it like that, because you dont know when the commandAction will run. In this method you just give it as a listener.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work as you expected.

I see there are already some solutions, but I feel a bit more discussion about what is actually going on might be helpful.

When you call the `frm.setCommandListener(new CommandListener() { ... })` the code presents the user with a dialog where she can type in some text and submit, but the code does not stop and wait until the user finishes.
Instead the code continues to execute - without yielding the result. Only after the user finished typing and submits, you get called back to process the result - which might happen much later, or not at all.

I guess you have some code calling this method like:

```
public void someMethod(int foo, String bar) {

   [...]
   String result = MyInputForm.showInputDialog();
   // do something with the result
   System.out.println("hey, got a result "+ result);
   [...]
}
```

Instead you need to reorganize this. First write a helper class handling the result:

public static class MyCallBack {

```
   public MyCallBack(... /* here pass in what you need to process the result*/) {
      ... remember necessary stuff in instance variables
   }

   public void processResult(String result) {
      // do something with the result
      System.out.println("hey, got a result "+ result);
      [...]
   }
```

}

then the calling side does just:

```
public void someMethod(int foo, String bar) {

   [...]
   MyInputForm.showInputDialog( new MyCallBack(... here pass in stuff ...) );
   [...]
}
```

and the actual code has to be changed to:

```
public static String showInputDialog(final MyCallBack callback) {
   Form frm = new Form();
   final Command cmd = new Command("Ok");
   final TextField txt = new TextField("Enter the text", null, 1024, 0);
   frm.addCommand(cmd);
   frm.append(txt);
   frm.setCommandListener(new CommandListener() {

       public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
            if (c == cmd) {
                return callback.processResult(txt.getString());
            } else {
                return; // or just omit the else part
            }
       }
   });
}
```

Two issues:

- this way of programming feels pretty backwards, but it is really the way it works.
- what feels not right is that I need to define a second helper class aside of the `CommandListener`. That is really not good style. I hope it can be improved, but as I do not see the complete code (which would be too much information anyway), I have to leave it to you to improve the code and get rid of the clutter. While I feel you want to have a modular, reusable input dialog helper, this might not be the best approach; better define the `Form`,`TextField` and `Command` directly where you need the result and get that running. Make it reusable in a second step after you get it running.

Answer (score 0):

Given that [CommandListener is fixed](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CommandListener.html), 2 possible options are

Use a class member variable in the outer class & assign to that variable instead

```
private static String myText;
...

public static String showInputDialog() {
   ...
   frm.setCommandListener(new CommandListener() {

       public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
            if (c == cmd) {
                myText = txt.getString(); 
            } else {
                myText = null;
            }
       }
   });
}
```

or Create a concrete implementation of your `CommandListener` and set the return value as a property of the new implementation

I would have a look at making the method/variable in this snippet *non-static*...

Comment: Please look in the comments below the question. Also, please show some code to elaborate how to use a class member variable to solve the problem

Comment: I want to create a static method that shows an input dialog. How can I return `myText` variable?

Comment: You wouldnt be returning any value as this is a restriction of the `CommandListener` interface. Instead you could set the class variable.

Comment: Sorry. I want the call to `showInputDialog` to be synchronized (i.e. it waits for the user to input and returns the result to the caller). For example, `String res = showInputDialog();`. How could I accomplish that with a member variable?

Comment: The `CommandListener` has to wait for an event, sry but don't think that doing this synchronously is the best approach...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return it if you instead do something with the String or store it somewhere, for example:

```
static String result;

public String commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
    if (c == cmd) {
        result = txt.getString();
    } else {
        result = null;
    }
}
```

Although you'll have threading issues to deal with.

Comment: I want to create a static method that shows an input dialog. How can I return `result` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You cant return the string because you dont know when the listener will be called.
You can do something with it once you have the string though.

```
public static void showInputDialog() {

   StringHandler sh = new StringHandler();

   frm.setCommandListener(new CommandListener() {

       public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
            if (c == cmd) {
                sh.handle(txt.getString()); 
            } else {
                sh.handle(null);
            }
       }
 });}


public class StringHandler {
    public void handle(String s){
        // Do something with that string.
    }
}
```

Comment: `String res = showInputDialog();`. How could I accomplish that with another method call `handle`?

Comment: As @Reimeus and I tried to tell you, getting this value synchronously is a bad approach. You need to use some sort of callback (as we both tried to show you). So instead of calling res = showInputDialog() in some method, StringHandler should do what you need to do when you have the input.